# Coloring multiple blocks at once

Tags: color

When I attempt to color multiple blocks the originally selected block is the only one that is effected.

I have created a plank tower that I intend to change from being white. I'm having issues transferring all the blocks to a new color. Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you ask about materials for objects? Or compositing of rendered image?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the material normally will only affect the active object, not all selected ones.

To fix this, change the material like you just did where it only affects one object, then press Control + L, and select Material, and it will copy the material to all other selected objects.

Hope that helps!